# creating R package and input the raw data

Tags: r, r-package

I want to create the R package to share the regression method created based on my dataset with coworkers.
As the first step, I tried to load my dataset as the raw data. I tried to follow the instructions in GitHub. But it didn't work. Could you help me to share this dataset via my own R package?

First, I install the devtools, roxygen2, here functions. And create the package

```
install.packages('devtools')
install.packages('roxygen2')
install.packages('here')
library(devtools)
library(roxygen2)
library(here)
devtools::create("Jpackage")
```

I also created the file (filename is data-raw) through the 'create a new file' button in R studio. And I put my dataset (csv file) into the data-raw file.

[creating file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q63Hn.png)

[put the dataset into the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dByjB.png)

Then, I used the use_data_raw() function, but it did not work.

```
usethis::use_data_raw()
```

I tried to other way. input the dataset and export it as an rda file. but it did not work.

```
data1_raw<-readr::read_csv("data-raw/data1.csv")
usethis::use_data(data1_raw,overwite=TRUE)
```

So, I created the data.frame in the R studio and output it as rda file.

```
width<-c(0.1561,0.1321,0.8137,0.8413)
length<-c(0.8121,0.6845,0.9841,0.3154)
data1<-data.frame(width,length)
usethis::use_data(data1).
```

However, it didn't work again. I failed to use all method..
Two types of errors pop up.
I don't know how to solve this problem.

the error messages are followed.
[error message about the path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzzvH.png)

(due to this message, I set the path using setwd(). But the codes previously mentioned didn't still work).

[error message about the existing named objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJcrQ.png)